# Swift How can I fix geocodeAddressString unmatched adress

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, geocoding

I want to zoom mapview according to giving address with `Mapview` and I use

```
   let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    var regionInMeterForList : Double = 7500

    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) {
            placemarks, error in
            let placemark = placemarks?.first
        
        print(self.address)
        let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = (placemark?.location!.coordinate)!

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: coordinates, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeterForList, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeterForList)
        self.mapVieww.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
```

I'm fetching address from server and it has lots of data.My issue is , if addresses doesn't match to `map` geocode can not find coordinates

Example:

Let's say my adress is `"New York City"` but in map , its declared as `"New York"` so when program try to find `"New York City"` coordinates, it gives error :

```
optional(Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)")
```

So, How can I fix if address doesnt match the mapview's declared addresses? or Is there a method that find possible addresses which contains in giving adress?